# Clash between mismath's \C and babel with russian

Tags: math-mode, babel

The following MWE shows that the definition

```
\mm@macro{C}{\ensuremath{\mathset{C}}\xspace}
```

from line 267 of `mismath.sty` [2023/02/24 v2.5] —

```
\mm@macro{C}{\ensuremath{\mathset{C}}\xspace}
```

— causes an error when paired with loading `babel` [2023/02/13 3.86]with option `russian` [`russianb.ldf` 2021/01/10 1.3m; russian 2020/09/09 1.3k]:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF}

\usepackage{mismath}

\begin{document}
$1+2=3$
\end{document}
```

The purpose of the offending line in `mismath.sty` is ultimately to define `\C` to give a blackboard bold C.

The error is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mismath/mismath.sty:267: LaTeX Err
or: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.267 ...macro{C}{\ensuremath{\mathset{C}}\xspace}
```

This is a new error not occurring with earlier versions of `mismath` and `babel`.

Is there some fix other than to make a copy of `\mismath` in which the offending line is commented out?

Comment: It's an error of `mismath` to try and define `\C`. In a wrong way, by the way, with `\ensuremath` and `\xspace`.

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr

There's a bug in `mismath.sty`: in the code of `\mm@macro` there's `\\mm@warning{#1}` that should be `\mm@warning{#1}`.

---

It's a common problem with packages that are essentially collections of macros to eventually clash with other packages.

In the specific case, the check done by `\mm@macro` should be delayed at begin document. When Cyrillic encodings are loaded, `\C` gets defined by `hyperref`. Similarly for `\mm@operator`. Even without `hyperref` there may be problems, because `unicode-math` does most of its job at begin document.

The code

```
\newcommand\mm@macro[2]{
    \@ifundefined{#1}{
        \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}
    }{\\mm@warning{#1}}
}
\newcommand\mm@operator[3][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\def\tempa{#3}}{\def\tempa{#1}}
    \@ifundefined{\tempa}{
        \DeclareMathOperator{#2}{#3}
    }{\mm@warning{\tempa}}
}
```

should be

```
\newcommand\mm@macro[2]{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifundefined{#1}{%
        \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
    }{\mm@warning{#1}}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\mm@operator{O{#3}mm}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifundefined{#1}{%
        \DeclareMathOperator{#2}{#3}%
    }{\mm@warning{#1}}%
  }%
}
```

(note the wrong `\\mm@warning` in the code for `\mm@macro`), which is the actual source of the error you get.

Anyway, doing

```
\mm@macro{C}{\ensuremath{\mathset{C}}\xspace}
```

is of dubious usefulness: there's no gain whatsoever in using `\xspace` just to be able to type `\C` in text instead of `$\C$` that's clearly segregates math.

Comment: Still, even with that fix, using $\C$ causes the error `Command \C invalid in math mode on input line [xx].` (I actually use $\CC$ instead of $\C$ for complex number set.)

Comment: @murray You’re being warned that `\C` isn’t redefined bu the package.

Comment: There is a gain: you don't need to type the $$ around the \C if you would not have needed the $$ anyway. // What would you recommend instead of \xspace? I know some people deprecate it but I have not yet come across a recommendation of an alternative.

Comment: @RosieF not using `$` is a disadvantage not an advantage. TeX is designed so it is clear whether you are in math or not, for human readers, for syntax highlighters, editors, ...   I wrote `xspace` but I would not recommend it in general and stronger than that I would discourage its use in math.

Comment: @RosieF I see no gain at all. I’ve seen so many times junk such as “Let x denote” instead of “Let $x$ denote”. Anything that encourages sloppiness is to be avoided.

Comment: I understand the point of view of egreg and David Carlisle about segregation between math and text. Nevertheless, when I use \C or \R in text mode (very often), it's just a symbol, it's not an equation, why refrain of using it? should we use another macro name for the symbol in text mode? I think its convenient so, but I would not want to "encourage sloppiness".

Comment: @AntoineMissier Use `$\C$`: where's the problem? It's a *math* symbol. Better yet, use `\CC` instead of `\C`, but this is personal preference. Also `x` is just a symbol not a math formula, but you type “let $x$ denote”, don't you?

Comment: @egreg I'm not totally convinced about the heresy of using \C or \R to represent the "special symbols" for sets of numbers in text mode without the math delimiters. Perhaps I will reconsider this point in a future release... I don't know, really it's convenient so.

Comment: @egreg I finally opted for rigor and posted a new release. Symbols for sets of numbers are now only available in math mode. This ugly mistake in mismath is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Murray for the post and to egreg for the answer. A new release will be uploaded very soon with the bug corrected `\mm@warning` instead of `\\mm@warning`, and with a simple solution when using babel with russian: not defining `\C` in that case!

A first immediate solution is to use `\let\C\relax` just after loading mismath, and this is why I am not thrilled to use `\AtBeginDocument` for all my macros.

Another issue "dubious usefulness" pointed by Enrico Gregorio is the use with `\ensuremath` and `\xspace`: indeed it is for using \C (and the other commands for numbers sets) directly in text, what is very common.

Antoine Missier

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676957/clash-between-mismaths-c-and-babel-with-russian#comment1682825_676960

Answer (score 0):

The new release has been uploaded on CTAN and should become available in a few days. Thanks for this bug report.

Comment: The package update is already available from now on.